# gprof gives Dwarf Error

Tags: apache, gcc, debian, gprof, dwarf

I have compiled my apache2 on different server with `gcc` options,

```
-pg -DGPROF -g -DNO_USE_SIGACTION
```

I copied this apache2 binary to different server and executed it once and got `gmon.out`.

But when creating the analysis file using command,

```
gprof /usr/sbin/apache2 /gmon.out > /tmp/apa.txt
```

I get following lines of error,

```
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '0', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '715', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '59393', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
```

Around 100 lines of similar error. **How can get rid of this to generate the gprof analysis file?**

Compilation OS:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.7

gcc version 4.8.1 (crosstool-NG 1.19.0)
```

Execution OS:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
6.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a newer version of GCC, but it sounds like you have a somewhat older version of gprof.

One fix would be to build and install your own gprof.  This isn't too hard.

Another fix would be to rebuild with "-gdwarf-3", which will tell GCC to use DWARF 3.